ASP.NET Core 8: Return 404 for every POST action that is outside of /api
Current situation: I run some controllers under /api/* and an SPA under /en/*
Some crappy crawler or bots make some invalid POST calls like /en/index.php that does not exists.
This results in an exception like this:
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.                                                                                                                           
      System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/en/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.

Is it possible to return an clean 404 on every post action that is not handled by /api?

I found a answer:
WebApplication app = builder.Build();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string path = context.Request.Path.Value ?? string.Empty;
    if (context.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethods.Post, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !path.StartsWith("/api"))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Found");
        return;
    }
    await next(context);
});

It checks if the request is a POST and does not starts with /api and then returns a 404.
It works but optimizations are welcome!
